# white border/line color set on hover for the bubbles in the bubble chart not being reset on mouse out from bubble

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

I'm trying to set a white border/line color on hover for the bubbles in the bubble chart. I am able to achieve that but,
1. on mouse out the white border/line color still stays and doesn't reset back to the default line color.
2. And how do i increase the width of the stroke outside the bubble?

Please help. Here is the demo:http://jsfiddle.net/JKLzy/17/

```
plotOptions:{
            bubble:{
              allowPointSelect:true,
              marker: {
                lineColor:'',
                  states:{
                    hover:{
                      enabled:true,
                      lineWidth:1,
                      lineColor:'white'
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              states:{
                hover:{
                  marker:{
                       lineWidth:0,
                      lineColor:'white'           
                  }
                }
              }
            },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it seems to stick to the white after hover ends is that in your code you've set the marker line color to `lineColor:''`. This is not a valid color. Remove it and your hover line effect should work correctly.

To adjust the width of the stroke just change `lineWidth`.

For example your finished `plotOptions.bubble.marker`-options could look like this:

```
marker: {
    states:{
        hover:{
            lineWidth: 3,
            lineColor: 'white'
        }
    }
}
```

See [this JSFiddle demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/JKLzy/19/).